# Upgrade SQLite Library for php 5.4

Tags: php, pecl, sqlite, pdo

My php version is 5.4

This is what I get in phpinfo

```
pdo_sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x   enabled
SQLite Library  3.6.20
```

I really need to update this driver.

On PHP 5.3 you could do this with commands like **yum install php5-sqlite**, but now it seems I have to use pecl.

For the command **pecl install  pdo_sqlite**, I get this:

```
/var/tmp/PDO_SQLITE/sqlite_driver.c: In function 'do_callback':
/var/tmp/PDO_SQLITE/sqlite_driver.c:311: error: 'zend_fcall_info' has no member named 'object_pp'
/var/tmp/PDO_SQLITE/sqlite_driver.c: At top level:
/var/tmp/PDO_SQLITE/sqlite_driver.c:636: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
/var/tmp/PDO_SQLITE/sqlite_driver.c: In function 'make_filename_safe':
/var/tmp/PDO_SQLITE/sqlite_driver.c:645: error: 'struct _php_core_globals' has no member named 'safe_mode'
/var/tmp/PDO_SQLITE/sqlite_driver.c:645: error: 'CHECKUID_CHECK_FILE_AND_DIR' undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/PDO_SQLITE/sqlite_driver.c:645: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/var/tmp/PDO_SQLITE/sqlite_driver.c:645: error: for each function it appears in.)
/var/tmp/PDO_SQLITE/sqlite_driver.c: In function 'pdo_sqlite_handle_factory':
/var/tmp/PDO_SQLITE/sqlite_driver.c:720: error: 'struct _php_core_globals' has no member named 'safe_mode'
make: *** [sqlite_driver.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

How could you solve this? If possible I would like not to recompile php - this could cause some problems on the production server.

My server is CentOS release 6.4

Thank you

Comment: Where did you install PHP from on this server? And why hasn't the server had security updates in two years?

Comment: I installed php from the repo remi. What do you mean by security updates? Should I update centos to 7